# Deployed Google chrome extension not installing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have deployed an google chrome extension on the google chrome web store this is the 1.4 version before this it was edited 3 times , but now whenever I try to install on my chrome browser it is giving an error saying There was a problem adding the item to Chrome. Please refresh the page and try again. and I cannot install it on my system . What must be the problem

> [image link](http://blog.ponder.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ponder-screenshot.png)
>    source :google

Comment: It would be a good idea to point out what changes you made between 1.3 and 1.4, and if the extension worked prior to these changes.

Comment: after making changes i removed my earlier extension from chrome and installed new version it was working fine but on all other systems it is not installing now . what must be the issue?

Comment: What I mean is, what programming changes did you make? Does the extension rely on anything already installed on a machine? Have you forgotten to implement some temporary data? What does the new extension do that the old one didn't, and vice versa?

Comment: ohk i will revert those changes and see then

Comment: There are possibly errors with the manifest file that uploader sanity checks didn't catch. Post your 1.4 manifest?

Comment: Which extension is it?

Comment: it worked finally . I think it was not installing because it takes 60 min or something to process in that time no one can install that perticular extension

Answer (score -1):

I was getting problem because I was trying to download when google was processing it . You should download after 30 minutes of deployment